# HTML content not visible on Safari (iOS) after scroll-to-top

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I recently built a one-pager website which when scrolled from mid / bottom to the top doesn´t show parts of the first section (intro) e.g. the white SVG slogan.

Here is the website: https://shorturl.at/kCMP6

How to reproduce it: On mobile Safari just scroll down 2 - 3 sections, then press the top-button, after that most of the time some significant parts of the first section (intro) are not visible/shown.

For clarification, there is no CSS entity that´s applied, I checked for that ofc.

I tried to disable the animations which are used on the first section (intro) images which seems to fix the described problem on Safari ( on MacOS only).

Some thoughts on this problem: Maybe a problem with a built-in lazy-load by Safari? Maybe a problem with the rendering by Safari?

I am thankful for every direction / thought provided regarding this topic!

Thanks in advance.